# How to make my Rect avoiding another Rect (canvas)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a little game on JavaScript and have a problem, Example: I have my square move randomly and one red square always standing (not move), when my square touch the red square, it will automacally find the way avoid the red square, but i don't know how to make my square find its way through the red square. I'm using canvas withmethod canvas.drawRect.

[imgur.com/a/7e93Xn6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cpfq.jpg), Here is my square, i want it  move up or down automacaly to avoid the red square, but don't know how to make it, Thanks

Comment: This description is very confusing... could you add a drawing / mockup of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7e93Xn6,
I want my square move up or down automacaly to avoid the red square, but don't know how to make it, Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this was not helpful either. I'll try to rephrase your question: you want your square to bounce off on the red square... Is that it?

Comment: Yeah, like that, like you avoid the car when the car try to hit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not too complicated you just have to continually check if those two squares will touch if one of them is moving. This can be calculated using it's screen positions and size. If those are about to collide move sideways as long as moving forward would still lead into the other square.
Here's a quick example:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Squares = function(xPos, yPos, wid, hei, col) {
  this.x = xPos;
  this.y = yPos;
  this.width = wid;
  this.height = hei;
  this.color = col;
  this.speed = 0;
}
var redSquare = new Squares(200, 100, 40, 40, "#ff0000");
var blueSquare = new Squares(0, 100, 40, 40, "#0000ff");
blueSquare.speed = 3;
var squares = [redSquare, blueSquare];

function loop() {

  if (blueSquare.x + blueSquare.width + blueSquare.speed > redSquare.x && blueSquare.y + blueSquare.height > redSquare.y) {
    blueSquare.x = redSquare.x - blueSquare.width;
    blueSquare.y -= blueSquare.speed;
  } else {
    blueSquare.x += blueSquare.speed;
  }
  if (blueSquare.x > canvas.width) {
    blueSquare.x = 0;
    blueSquare.y = 100;
  }
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var a = 0; a < squares.length; a++) {
    context.fillStyle = squares[a].color;
    context.fillRect(squares[a].x, squares[a].y, squares[a].width, squares[a].height);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval(loop, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need, i have read a lot of AI before you answer, save my life